# LWC Data Table not getting refreshed on click of delete button

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, refresh

LWC Data table is not getting refreshed on delete of a row. code below:

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track,api } from 'lwc';
import distProfileShareList from '@salesforce/apex/DistributorProfileShareLWC.distProfileShareList';
import { deleteRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import deleteDistributorBPFocusAreaShareRecords from '@salesforce/apex/DistributorProfileShareLWC.deleteDistributorBPFocusAreaShareRecords';
const columns = [
    {
         label: 'User',
         fieldName: 'User',
         type: 'text',
         fixedWidth: 300
     },
      {
         label: 'AccessLevel',
         fieldName: 'AccessLevel',
         type: 'text',
         fixedWidth: 300
     },
     {
        label: 'Id',
        fieldName: 'Id',
        type: 'text',
        fixedWidth: 300,
        hideLabel:true
    },
    {
        label: 'RowCause',
        fieldName: 'RowCause',
        type: 'text',
        fixedWidth: 300,
        hideLabel:true
    },
 ] 
export default class DistributorProfileShare extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = columns;
    @track data=[];
    @api recordId; 
    @track distributorProfileRec;
    @track userId;
    @track accessLevel;
    @track selectedRecIdValue;
    @track dpShareRecords = [];
    @api distributorProfileId;
    @api strRecordId;
    @api selectedDistributorProfileIdList=[];
    @track errorMsg;
    @track recordsCount = 0;
    refreshTable;
    @wire(distProfileShareList,{ distributorProfileId: '$strRecordId'}) 
    distributorProfileRec({ error, data }) {
        this.refreshTable=data;
        if(data) {
            let currentData = [];
            this.data = data.map((row) => ({ 
                User: row.UserOrGroup.Name,
                AccessLevel : row.AccessLevel,
                Id: row.Id,
                RowCause:row.RowCause}));
                console.log('###### allData is ######### '+ JSON.stringify(data)); 
        }
        else if(error) {
            window.console.log(error);
        }
    }
    getSelectedIdAction(event){
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        window.console.log('selectedRows# ' + JSON.stringify(selectedRows));
        for (let i = 0; i<selectedRows.length; i++){
            alert("You selected: " + selectedRows[i].Id);
             this.selectedDistributorProfileIdList.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
        }
    }
    deleteDistributorShareRowAction(){
       deleteDistributorBPFocusAreaShareRecords({recordIds:this.selectedDistributorProfileIdList}) 
       .then(()=>{
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').selectedRows=[];
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                message:'Record deleted successfully',         
                variant:'success'
            });
            window.alert('Record Has been deleted on line 83 ### ');
            this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            return refreshApex(this.refreshTable); // this method not working.
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            this.errorMsg =error;
            window.console.log('unable to delete the record due to ' + JSON.stringify(this.errorMsg));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your post. I've fixed the code for you.

Comment: this.data = ... part could have used the rest operator to write just: `this.data = data.map((row) => ({ ...row, User: row.UserOrGroup.Name }));`, since you just want to add an additional property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
distributorProfileRec({ error, data }) {
    this.refreshTable=data;
```

Should be:

```
distributorProfileRec(response) {
    this.refreshTable = response;
    const { data, error } = response;
```

In most cases, you only care about data and error, but if you need to use `refreshApex`, you need the entire `response`, which includes the information that `refreshApex` needs to call Apex and refresh the cache. This is true for both imperative and wire Apex calls.